# Centering items in <div> HTML

Tags: html, css

want to center labels & textbox in a form in .
HTML code:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>     
<body>
    <div id="table">
        </br><label for="sFX">F(X)</label><input name="sFX" id="inpBox" type="text" value=""/>
        </br><label for="x0">X0</label><input name="x0" id="inpBox" type="text" value=""/>
        </br><label for="x1">X1</label><input name="x1" id="inpBox" type="text" value=""/>
        </br></label><input id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="process()"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
#table{
background-color:lightblue;
width:400px;
height:200px;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:lightblue;
text-align:right;   
 }

#inpBox{
width: 100px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 }

label {
   width: 20px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;   
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I found no way to get the items to be centered. What to do ?

Comment: Please code in structured way... and for #table write ''text-align:center;''

Comment: The formatting of your post is broken, as you would have noticed had you spent one second looking at it after posting. You can not merely put `<div>` in the middle of your post, you need to delimit it with eg backticks. Read the posting guidelines. Also, please search for your own answer to this, since it has been asked and answered dozens if not hundreds of times. It may be the single most popular question on SO. I would search for a duplicate myself to close this in favor of but frankly it's just not worth anyone's time. Also, what is `</br>` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    #table {
      background-color: lightblue;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      background-color: lightblue;
      text-align: center;
      padding:20px;
    }
    table{
     margin:0 auto;
    }
    #inpBox {
      width: 100px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    label {
      width: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="table">
        <table style="">
         <tr>
          <td><label for="sFX">F(X)</label>
          </td>
          <td><input name="sFX" id="inpBox" type="text" value="" />
          </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
          <td><label for="x0">X0</label>
          </td>
          <td><input name="x0" id="inpBox" type="text" value="" />
          </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
          <td><label for="x1">X1</label>
          </td>
          <td><input name="x1" id="inpBox" type="text" value="" />
          </td>
          </tr>
<tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:left"><input id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="process()" />
          </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        
      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Probably because you should have voted to close as a duplicate instead of answering for the 100th time.

Comment: ?? You're saying no-one has asked how to center things in CSS before, and/or you are the first person in the history of 10M questions on Stack Overflow to come up with this solution?

Comment: @Anil Thanks, it was ok.

Comment: welcome Ebitc, and @torazaburo. i m saying about this question not 10M questions.

Answer (score -1):

Use `text-align: center;` to align the elements in center horizontally.

```css
#table {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#inpBox {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
label {
  width: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
table {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table">
    </br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="sFX">F(X)</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="sFX" id="inpBox" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="x0">X0</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="x0" id="inpBox" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="x1">X1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="x1" id="inpBox" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
          <input id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="process()" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

here you go
https://jsfiddle.net/4r6h8u5c/

```
<div id="table">
    <label for="sFX">
      <span>F(X)</span>
      <input name="sFX" class="inpBox" type="text" value=""/>
    </label>
    <label for="x0">
    <span>X0</span>
      <input name="x0" class="inpBox" type="text" value=""/></label>
    <label for="x1">
    <span>X1</span>
      <input name="x1" class="inpBox" type="text" value=""/></label>
    <div class="submit">
    <input id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start" onclick="process()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#table {
    background - color: lightblue;
    width: 400 px;
    height: 200 px;
    display: block;
    background - color: lightblue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.inpBox {
    width: 100 px;
    margin - left: auto;
    margin - right: auto;
}

label {
    display: block;
    text - align: center;
}
label span {
    display: inline - block;
    text - align: right;
    width: 70 px;
}
.submit {
    margin - top: 40 px;
    text - align: center;
}
```

i cleaned up your html and css too. Remember id's are meant to be unique and not reused for different elements, instead use classes.

Comment: How does this center the elements as the OP wants?

Comment: @torazaburo have you checked the fiddle? the html was posted to illustrate my point of refraining from using an id more than once. in the OP's case id="inpBox"

Comment: @omarCreativeDev - put the relevant css changes in your answer here, not just in the jsfiddle.